# push_back of STL list got bad performance?

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote a simple program to test STL list performance against a simple C list-like data structure. It shows bad performance at "push_back()" line. Any comments on it?

```
$ ./test2
 Build the type list : time consumed -> 0.311465
 Iterate over all items: time consumed -> 0.00898
 Build the simple C List: time consumed -> 0.020275
 Iterate over all items: time consumed -> 0.008755
```

The source code is:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include "high_resolution_timer.hpp"

#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


#define TESTNUM 1000000

/* The test struct */
struct MyType {
    int num;
};


/*
 * C++ STL::list Test
 */
typedef struct MyType* mytype_t;

void myfunction(MyType t) {
}

int test_stl_list()
{
    std::list<mytype_t> mylist;
    util::high_resolution_timer t;

    /*
     * Build the type list
     */
    t.restart();
    for(int i = 0; i < TESTNUM; i++) {
        mytype_t aItem;
        aItem->num = i;
        mylist.push_back(aItem);
    }
    std::cout << " Build the type list : time consumed -> " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;


    /*
     * Iterate over all item
     */
    t.restart();
    std::for_each(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), myfunction);
    std::cout << " Iterate over all items: time consumed -> " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

/*
 * a simple C list
 */
struct MyCList;
struct MyCList{
    struct MyType m;
    struct MyCList* p_next;
};

int test_simple_c_list()
{
    struct MyCList* p_list_head = NULL;
    util::high_resolution_timer t;

    /*
     * Build it
     */
    t.restart();
    struct MyCList* p_new_item = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < TESTNUM; i++) {
        p_new_item = (struct MyCList*) malloc(sizeof(struct MyCList));
        if(p_new_item == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR : while malloc\n");
            return -1;
        }
        p_new_item->m.num = i;
        p_new_item->p_next = p_list_head;
        p_list_head = p_new_item;
    }
    std::cout << " Build the simple C List: time consumed -> " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;

    /*
     * Iterate all items
     */
    t.restart();
    p_new_item = p_list_head;
    while(p_new_item->p_next != NULL) {
        p_new_item = p_new_item->p_next;
    }
    std::cout << " Iterate over all items: time consumed -> " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(test_stl_list() != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: error at testcase1\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(test_simple_c_list() != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: error at testcase2\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Oops, Yes.
I modified the code, and it show:

```
$ ./test2
 Build the type list : time consumed -> 0.163724
 Iterate over all items: time consumed -> 0.005427
 Build the simple C List: time consumed -> 0.018797
 Iterate over all items: time consumed -> 0.004778
```

So, my question is, why my "push_back" code got bad performance?

Comment: One (unrelated) comment would be that you should use `new MyType` instead of the raw `malloc`.

Comment: Also, make sure you do any testing with optimizations all the way. By the way, `list` is a last-resort container, `vector` or `deque` is usually a much better choice.

Comment: @sth:Generally he shouldn't use either one -- he should just store raw MyType objects and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your STL codes create a memory piece twice for each cell.
The following is from STL 4.1.1 on x86_64

```
void push_back(const value_type& __x)
{
   this->_M_insert(end(), __x);
}


// Inserts new element at position given and with value given.
void _M_insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
{
   _Node* __tmp = _M_create_node(__x);     // Allocate a new space ####
   __tmp->hook(__position._M_node);
}
```

As you can see, also, push_back() function calls several more functions before returning to the caller, and
few pointer-value copying occurs everytime one of the functions is called.
Might be neligible because all the parameters are passed by const-reference though.

Comment: Oh, yes. So, what does the "hook" do? I can't find the source code of my g++-4.4.0, x86_64.

Comment: In many linux distributions, it is located under /usr/include/c++. Since all STL routines are implemented in a header file, all the header files, such as iostream, list, vector, and any other *files* included by #include, contain all the implementations. It means your system has the entire source of STL as long as you can use and compile STL templates. As for hook, it is not a STL function, but a part of libstdc++. Look at the following thread: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread165075.html

Answer (score 3):

Well one thing is that in C, you have a linked list of objects but in C++, you have a linked list of pointers (so for one thing, you are doing twice as many allocations).  To compare apples to apples, your STL code should be:

```
int test_stl_list()
{
    std::list<MyType> mylist;
    util::high_resolution_timer t;

    /*
     * Build the type list
     */
    t.restart();
    for(int i = 0; i < TESTNUM; i++) {
        MyItem aItem;
        aItem.num = i;
        mylist.push_back(aItem);
    }
    std::cout << " Build the type list : time consumed -> " << t.elapsed() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My question is to test the performance C-like structure against STL List. I don't care the order of data. I want compare the performance of "build" and "iterate".

Comment: @LeonZhang - I'm not the person who made a comment about order.  But your C list and your C++ list are **different**.  Your C++ list is the equivalent of the C list `struct MyCList{ struct MyType *m; struct MyCList* p_next; };` (note that MyCList::m is now a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you're doing a `push_front`, not a `push_back` (in your own implementation, that is).

Second, you should also compare `std::slist` for a fair comparison as the `std::list` is double-linked.

Third, you need to use right compiler flags for a fair comparison. With gcc you should at least compile with `-O2`. Without optimization, STL always sucks because no inlining is done and there is lots of function call overhead.

Comment: `slist` isn't part of the standard library, actually.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your `high_resolution_timer` class is measuring more than just the routines you are trying to measure. I would refactor the code such that the *only* code between `t.restart()` and `t.elapsed()` is what you are keen on measuring. All other code therein could have unknown performance implications that could skew your results.